# How do I print my function using printf?

Tags: perl

I have written a function that is a countdown timer.

I want to print this way,  Starts in 00:05

Hence I did this, but it doesn't print correctly, it overwrites my sentence. Can you help fix it?

```
printf("\nStarts in %02d:%02d",countdownsleep(5));

# Sub for countdown
sub countdownsleep {
    my $x = shift;
    my $t = 1 *$x;
    my ($m,$s);
    my $stoptime = time + $t;
     while((my $now = time) < $stoptime) {
   #printf( "%02d:%02d\r", ($stoptime - $now) / 60, ($stoptime - $now) % 60);
   $m = ($stoptime - $now) / 60;
   $s = ($stoptime - $now) % 60;
    select(undef,undef,undef,1);
 }
 return ($m,$s);
}
```

Comment: It prints the correct value ie `00:01` that is the last computed one.

Comment: Ofcourse it did. The problem was, it printed it on top of my sentence `Starts in `. I want to avoid that. That is what I was trying to ask. I wanted it to print the count timer only at the end of my sentence, the whole time. For ex: Lift off in 00:05 seconds. Basically, want the subroutine to print countdown where you call it., and also be able to re-use it anytime. I am passing the sleeptime in seconds as I call the subroutine countdownsleep().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `\r` (carriage return) - it returns the carriage **to the very start of string** (thus overwriting the first 5 characters in the best case scenario); AND causes weird printing behavior in the absence of "`\n`" (thus possibly not printing anything else after 5 characters).

---

To fix your problem, you need to do this **in your loop** inside countdownsleep ():

```
$prefix = "Starts in "; # could be passed in as parameter to countdownsleep()
printf( "$prefix %02d:%02d\r", ($stoptime - $now) / 60
                               , ($stoptime - $now) % 60);
# NOTE this ^^^ - now you re-print your prefix every time and not lose due to \r
```

And in your call:

```
countdownsleep(5); print "\n"; # printing is done by the loop inside already
# or if you added a $prefix parameter to it:
countdownsleep("Starts in ", 5); print "\n";
```

---

Here is why you need to print "\n" at the VERY END

```
$ perl -e '{print "1234567"; printf("1\r");}'

$ perl -e '{print "1234567"; printf("8\r"); print "\n";}' # Works now
12345678

# And this is what CR really dows
$ perl -e '{print "1234567"; printf("z\r");  printf("yy\r");  print "\n";}'
yy34567z
$ perl -e '{print "1234567"; printf("z\r");  printf("yy\r");  print "zzzz";}'
zzzz
```

---

In other words, printing a carriage return (`\r`) at the end of the string WITHOUT newline (`\n`) **will effectively not print the string at all** - more specifically, will erase everything that was suppose to be printed.

Printing (`\r`) before some other characters in the string will cause the subsequent characters to be printed from the beginning of the line, overwriting existing characters (as many as the new ones), but will keep the subsequent characters intact - with the caveat that the non-overwritten characters won't be printed unless `\n` is printed at the end.

- `print "$something\r"; # prints nothing`
- `print "$something\r$finish"; # prints $finish but not $something`

  ```
  # $finish is assumed to not contain "\r"
  ```
- `print "$something\r$finish\n";`

  ```
  # * prints $something (entirely)
  # * Moves to start of the line
  # * prints $finish overwriting as many characters  from $somthing as needed
  # * prints the rest of $something if it was longer than $finish
  # * prints newline.
  ```

---

On a different note, you should consider using existing coundown/progress CPAN modules instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Hi Mr. DVK. but I need to use that sub-routine many times, and hence, I cannot put the text `Starts in `  inside my subroutine. Hence why, when I tried to call, I would first print my text `Starts in `,or 'Stops in` and then call the subroutine `countdownsleep(x)`. Also, note, I had commented the `printf` statement inside my subroutine and decided to return it, but still didn't work :(. I used `\r` because I want to print the countdown on the same exact spot, not in newlines.

Comment: @youhaveaBigego - whatever you do, EVERY time you print the timer value you need to prepend it with a "starts in" prefix to avoid your problem. You can parametrize th prefix ("starts in" or "stops in") if you need

Comment: I am trying to avoid writing multiple subroutines which makes no sense. I think by the sentence 'you need to prepend it with a "starts in" prefix to avoid your problem' you are thinking, I should prepend it when i make my function call like `printf("\nStart in %d:%d\n",countdownsleep(5));` then you understood my question. I certainly dont want to put any text inside my subroutine. I only want the sub to print the countdown time.

Comment: @youhaveaBigego - You can not do that without using ANSI terminal control. If you print "\r", you **must** re-print the prefix again otherwise it will be lost. Just the way `\r` works

Comment: @youhaveaBigego - however, if you add "`$prefix`" parameter to your subroutine, you only need one, like I showed

Answer (score 0):

You are "suffering from buffering". Set `$|--` at the beginning to turn the buffering off for standard output.

Comment: How is buffering related to this when the problem would exist even after Perl interpreter process exits? See examples in my answer

Comment: Just to be clear - buffeing MAY also cause a problem, but not the one he is describing ( "it overwrites my sentence" )

Comment: The problem isn't that it isn't shown as per the Q. It's "it doesn't print correctly, it overwrites my sentence". Meaning that if it was simply buffering, it wouldn't show ANYTHING, instead of incorrect thing

Comment: @DVK: Let's wait for the author to tell us.

Comment: I only used `\r` initially in my `printf` statement (which I then commented out) because I want the countdown timer to print on the same spot, not in 5 new lines. hence why I hesitated to use `\n`. Btw, the statement `select(undef,undef,undef,$t);` is used to sleep for **t** seconds.

Comment: @youhaveaBigego - just to be clear, you need `\n` **at the very end** after the last timer. You should still use `\r` between timers as you were doing to print on the same spot - see my answer for why it wasn't working exactly as needed

Comment: When I said, 'it overwrites my sentence', what I meant to say is, as the countdown time is being countdown and printed, it overwrites my sentence 'starts in'. I understand that I should give a `\n` after the time is printed for the next print statement. But the objective here is to print countdowntime(x) at any part of any sentence. For ex: I am going to have fun in **%d:%d** seconds. OR. For ex: Lift off in %d:%d seconds. I want to re-use the subroutine manytimes, and hence cannot put any text inside it.